# iOS Cordova/Ionic native function translations

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

How i can translate this Strings to other languages?
`Function call --> navigator.camera` 
Image --> http://subefotos.com/ver/?6056ec9093c812fd458faa96fa69d6a5o.jpg

Comment: this is system default language text this will change when you change iPhone language from setting..! I hope it help

Comment: I change but doesn't work that

Comment: open the project on xcode and add the localization for other languages